# AttributeError: 'ChessBoard' object has no attribute 'grid'

Tags: python

[click here for picture of code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/07GDP.png)

I keep getting an Attribute error saying that my object has not attribute grid. So far this is demo code from my class and it works on a demo.  Not sure whats going wrong, could it possibly be my environment? Still new to python, so if the answer is obvious, take it easy on me

```
class ChessBoard:
    white = (1,1,1)
    red = (1,.2,0)
    blue = (.1,.1,1)

    def _init_(self):
        self.grid = np.zeros((8,8,3))

    def render(self):
        plt.imshow(self.grid)

    def color_cell(self, row, col, color):
        self.grid[row, col] = color

board = ChessBoard()

board.render()
```

Comment: please provide the code in text format

Comment: Please repeat [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the
[intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).  Your question must be self-contained, and your problem must be reproducible.  An off-site link is not acceptable; an image of code is not acceptable.

Comment: sorry, I'm new to this.

Comment: Don't forget the `import` sections in your examples.

Answer (score 0):

TLDR; You have a typo in your `init` method. You want double underscores `__init__`.

Currently `_init_` is registered as *just another method on the class*.
So when you created `board = ChessBoard()`, default constructor is called and hence `grid` variable is not bound to `board`

Please do not post image snapshots of your code. Paste relevant parts of your code on SO

Comment: oh my Guess ive been lookin at code too long, thank your so much!

Comment: You're welcome. Happy learning, happens to everybody :).Please accept the answer and do keep in mind @Prune's comment